# Android - How to use ObjectAnimator in XML

Tags: android, android-animation

I simply want to use an `objectAnimator` which is defined in a XML-file. I want to put two `objectAnimators` and want to choose in my Code which I want to use.

This is how my XML-File looks like where I set the `propertyName`, that I wanna access later on in the code:

```
<?xml version"1.0" encodin="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="..."
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="animX"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:valueFrom="FFFFFF"
        android:valueTo="FF0000" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="animY"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:valueFrom="FF0000"
        android:valueTo="FFFFFF" />

</set>
```

That is the code, where I want to access to a `propertyName` defined `objectAnimator`:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "animX");
anim.setTarget(anim);
anim.start();
```

Unfortunately, that is not how it works and I am really struggling to find a solution to access the objectAnimators I want.

Answer (score 3):

One of two things are the issue:

1) each `ObjectAnimator` needs to be it's own and then added to a set after you inflate the animator (via `final ObjectAnimator animator = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, resID);`) and set it on the view

2) If the XML is giving you IDE errors, check that your `ObjectAnimators` are in the `/animator` folder and not the `/anim` folder in the `/res` directory

Edited: `/animators` was not recognized, but `/animator` was

Comment: error: android.animation.AnimatorSet cannot be cast to android.animation.ObjectAnimator

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting 2 `ObjectAnimators` in your XML file, you could rather use `PropertyValuesHolder` and wrap them in one `ObjectAnimator` like this:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse">

    <propertyValuesHolder
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="2" />

    <propertyValuesHolder
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="2" />

</objectAnimator>
```

Then you can retrieve this animation like this:

```
val scaleAnimation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(
        context, R.animator.your_anim_file_name)
scaleAnimation.setTarget('your_view')
scaleAnimation.start()
```

Or if you have multiple animations like this, you can add them in AnimatorSet and play sequentially or together.

```
val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
animatorSet.playSequentially(scaleAnimation, translateAnimation)
animatorSet.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not create your own objectanimators programatically ?

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator1 = new ObjectAnimator();
objectAnimator.setPropertyName("animX");
objectAnimator.setFloatValues(0, 1);
objectAnimator.setTarget(logoView);//call this when your ready to set target
objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
```

and then create another one and store them as instance variables perhaps ?

Update

So just create a anim folder  in res.  and create Two different xml files.  Call each one respectively.

Comment: I can, but I would like to put all the properties like duration, color value From/To in a XML-File and just load them programatically.